# Searchview keyboard won't pop up programatically when starting the activity in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I have a searchview widget in my activity that is not part of a toolbar. In my onCreate method I use 
searchView.setIconified(false);
and that does bring the searchView into focus, but it does not bring up the keyboard unless I click it again. How do I have they keyboard also pop up?

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@color/lighterGrey">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="@string/search_transition"
        android:background="@drawable/search_shape"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/acronym_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.setFocusable(true);
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm != null) {
    imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your AndroidManifest.xml. Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` to your Activity declaration. For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

`stateVisible` will show the software keyboard as soon as the Activity starts. `adjustPan` will adjust the view to compensate for the keyboard being shown (so that the content you're trying to show isn't covered by the keyboard).

Comment: [Have you tried showing the keyboard programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1) If that doesn't work, post code & XML so we can help you with your issue

Comment: Did you try setting focusableInTouchMode = true in the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following

> searchView.setFocusable(true); searchView.setIconified(false); searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();

It should focus and open keyboard. 
In some devices, you'll have to add also

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

`if (imm != null) {

imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);

 }`

Comment: Not working either :( I'm going to update the question with my code